# Arch and Windows 7 dual boot with encryption, replacing existing Linux install

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub2, dual-boot, disk-encryption

I have a computer with 3 hard drives:

- 120 GB SSD, which Arch identifies as `sdb`
- 1 TB spinny drive, which Arch identifies as `sdc`
- 160 GB spinny drive, which Arch identifies as `sda`

Currently, Windows 7 is installed on `sdb`. Some of the Windows related stuff is also on `sdc`, through symlinks and programs installed on that path, but that drive is mostly storage.

On `sda`, I had installed a Xubuntu 12.04. As part of that, GRUB was also installed, so now when the computer boots I get a GRUB menu, giving the options of booting into Windows 7 on `sdb` or Xubuntu on `sda`.

I have now decided that I don't care for Xubuntu, and would like to install Arch instead (by deleting all the `sda` partitions and creating new ones for Arch). On top of that, I would like to encrypt the whole `sda` with LUKS. I want to keep Windows 7 as dual boot, and I want a GRUB menu to pop up and ask whether to boot into Windows or Arch. If I choose Arch, it should then ask me for the LUKS encryption key.

How can I accomplish this? I'm not very experienced with Linux and a bit worried about messing up my Windows install too much. While the Arch wiki is very detailed and informative, the instructions for what I want seem split between different articles and I'm not sure how to combine them correctly. For instance, the [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) has very nice instructions for creating a partition table, but doesn't mention encryption. The [encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) page explains encryption, but does not explain how to get GRUB to work with it.

Specifically, I am confused about:

- I understand that with LUKS and full disk encryption, `/boot` must be unencrypted so that it can boot and give me the decryption key prompt, while everything else can be in the LVM/LUKS. Can this `/boot` be on `sda`?
- Do I have to install and configure GRUB from scratch (ie. run `fixmbr` from Windows to revert to a Windows-only boot state, then add GRUB from there)? How do I this? Is there a way to just point my existing GRUB to the unencrypted `/boot` and have Arch take care of things from there?
- How big should `/boot` be?
- Is there an easy, standard way of accomplishing what I want?

Or to summarize my question: *How do I install Arch so that it is on an encrypted drive and dual boots alongside Windows 7, when the computer already contains another (unencrypted) Linux installation, which I want to delete?*